# Shutdown jetty server by url

Tags: http, url, webserver, jetty, shutdown

Is there a way to shutdown Jetty server by url (HTTP request) ? 
The problem is that I need to shutdown a server that has been started by another project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the ShutdownHandler located in the jetty-server package.  Example setup is in the javadoc.

http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/ShutdownHandler.html